Should a tag for pirates splitting gold be added?
There are many different puzzles involving pirates who have to split gold coins and vote for proposals:
5 Negotiating Pirates Puzzle
5 Precommitting Pirates Puzzle
Pirates and gold coins
Five pirates splitting gold with a twist
Should there be a separate tag for pirates-and-gold?

Briefly discussed in chat
